# Kivy Widgets size management

Tags: python, kivy

I have a **BoxLayout** with a **Label** and two **TextInputs** on my PC. They are displayed like I want but not on some mobiles devices. When I work on my PC I modify `Window.size` to a medium size so in all devices the display shall be approximately the same.

**On my PC**:

[image: pc]

**On some mobile devices**:

[image: On mobiles]

I've tried to replace the **px** by **dp** on the size of those widgets, but it didn't make it. And I don't want to use `size_hint` everywhere, I also want to use fixed height and width. all help is greatly appreciated.

ps: the window size I use for the tests on pc is `(244.4, 483.2)` approximately the screen size of the little Iphone8

Answer (score 0):

If you put an id (for example **id: ti**) on your TextInput, then I believe you can set the height as **height: ti.texture_size[1]**. Perhaps adding some padding also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but If you look at the first picture you will see that every thing work on pc, the problem is with the mobile adaptation